# How to copy formula horizontally a variable number of times? - GoogleSheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset as seen below:

[image]

Column V to X (in grey) are populated from a form. Column X is the first date we recieve payment and column V is the number of months we will receive the payment for.

I want to dynamically calculate the value of each next payment date based on the amount of payments recieved. For example in the image above for cell Y2 I have a formula =X2+30 and I dragged this to the right until it reaches cell AD2. Column V is dynamic but won't exceed 10 and I always want to increase by 30 days in each column for the number of times in V2. The example is above ie. I don't have data in AF2 or AG2 because its not needed. But if the value was 9 then it would automatically add the value =AE2+30 to that cell.

Is there a way to do this without a script?

I also want to repeat the final date in column AH2. I tried to achieve this by typing the following:

[image]

But I get too large a number. How can I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in Y2 and copy over to AG2 and down the length of the data:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<$V2,X2+30,"")
```

Then in AH2

```
=X2+(30*(V2-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

**paste in Y2:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IF(LEN(V2:V), 
 {IF(COLUMN(A:A)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 1), ), 
  IF(COLUMN(B:B)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 2), ),
  IF(COLUMN(C:C)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 3), ),
  IF(COLUMN(D:D)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 4), ),
  IF(COLUMN(E:E)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 5), ),
  IF(COLUMN(F:F)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 6), ),
  IF(COLUMN(G:G)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 7), ),
  IF(COLUMN(H:H)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 8), ),
  IF(COLUMN(I:I)<$V2:V, EDATE(X2:X, 9), )}, )))
```

[image]

---

**paste in AH2:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(
 IF(AG2:AG<>"", AG2:AG,
 IF(AF2:AF<>"", AF2:AF,
 IF(AE2:AE<>"", AE2:AE,
 IF(AD2:AD<>"", AD2:AD,
 IF(AC2:AC<>"", AC2:AC,
 IF(AB2:AB<>"", AB2:AB,
 IF(AA2:AA<>"", AA2:AA,
 IF(Z2:Z<>"", Z2:Z,
 IF(Y2:Y<>"", Y2:Y, )))))))))))
```

[image]

---

---

**if you still want hard-static 30 days then:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IF(LEN(V2:V), 
 {IF(COLUMN(A:A)<$V2:V, X2:X+30, ), 
  IF(COLUMN(B:B)<$V2:V, X2:X+60, ),
  IF(COLUMN(C:C)<$V2:V, X2:X+90, ),
  IF(COLUMN(D:D)<$V2:V, X2:X+120, ),
  IF(COLUMN(E:E)<$V2:V, X2:X+150, ),
  IF(COLUMN(F:F)<$V2:V, X2:X+180, ),
  IF(COLUMN(G:G)<$V2:V, X2:X+210, ),
  IF(COLUMN(H:H)<$V2:V, X2:X+240, ),
  IF(COLUMN(I:I)<$V2:V, X2:X+270, )}, )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
=ArrayFormula(if(V2:V="","",if(column(Y:AG)-column(W:W)>V2:V,"",X2:X+(column(Y:AG)-column(X:X))*30)))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(if(V2:V="","",X2:X+(V2:V-1)*30))
```

in Google Sheets.